# Using apply to insert a value extracted from one column (with json type) to another one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataset:

```
userid   sub_id    event
1        NaN       {'score':25, 'sub_id':5}
1        5         {'score':1}
```

When `sub_id` column is **NaN**, I want to extract this information from `event` column using the following code:

```
df['sub_id'] = df.apply(lambda row: 
                        row['event'].split('sub_id')[1] 
                        if pd.isnull(row['sub_id']) 
                        else row['sub_id'])
```

However, I am receiving this error: `KeyError: ('sub_id', u'occurred at index index')`

I am trying to obtain this dataframe:

```
userid   sub_id    event
1        5         {'score':25, 'sub_id':5}
1        5         {'score':1}
```

Any idea for the error, or any suggestions for a different solution?

**UPDATE**

I need to extract the value that resides in a nested dict element:

```
event
{u'POST': {u'{"options_selected":{"Ideas":"0"},"criterion_feedback":{},"overall_feedback":"Feedback_text_goes_here_1"}': [u'']}, u'GET': {}}
```

I am using this code:

```
df['POST'] = df['event'].apply(pd.Series)['POST']
```

which creates the following column:

```
POST
{u'{"options_selected":{"Ideas":"0"},"criterion_feedback":{},"overall_feedback":"Feedback_text_goes_here_1"}': [u'']}
```

However, I need to get the `overall_feedback` value. Because of the formatting of the `POST` field, the following code does not work:

```
df['POST'].apply(pd.Series)['overall_feedback']
```

It throws this error `KeyError: 'overall_feedback'`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) or [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
print (type(df.loc[0, 'event']))
<class 'dict'>

df['sub_id'] = df['sub_id'].combine_first(df.event.apply(lambda x: x['score']))
#df['sub_id'] = df['sub_id'].fillna(df.event.apply(lambda x: x['score']))
print (df)
                       event  sub_id  userid
0  {'sub_id': 5, 'score': 5}     5.0       1
1               {'score': 1}     5.0       1
```

EDIT: If nested dict, faster solutio is use double `DataFame` constructor and slowier solution double `apply` with `Series`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'userid':[1,1],
                   'sub_id':[np.nan, 5],
                   'event':[{'post':{'score':25, 'sub_id':5}},{'post':{'score':1}} ]})

print (df)
                                  event  sub_id  userid
0  {'post': {'sub_id': 5, 'score': 25}}     NaN       1
1                {'post': {'score': 1}}     5.0       1

s = pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame(df['event'].values.tolist())['post'].values.tolist())['score']
print (s)
0    25
1     1
Name: score, dtype: int64
```

```
s = df['event'].apply(pd.Series)['post'].apply(pd.Series)['score']
print (s)
0    25.0
1     1.0
Name: score, dtype: float64
```

---

```
df['sub_id'] = df['sub_id'].combine_first(s)
print (df)
                                  event  sub_id  userid
0  {'post': {'sub_id': 5, 'score': 25}}    25.0       1
1                {'post': {'score': 1}}     5.0       1
```

EDIT1:

For converting to dict is possible use:

```
import ast, yaml

df = pd.DataFrame({'userid':[1,1],
                   'sub_id':[np.nan, 5],
                   'event':[{'post':{'score':25, 'sub_id':5}},{'post':{'score':1}} ]})

df.event = df.event.astype(str)
print (type(df.loc[0, 'event']))
<class 'str'>

df['event'] = df['event'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
#df['event'] = df['event'].apply(yaml.load)
print (df)
                                  event  sub_id  userid
0  {'post': {'sub_id': 5, 'score': 25}}     NaN       1
1                {'post': {'score': 1}}     5.0       1

print (type(df.loc[0, 'event']))
<class 'dict'>
```

EDIT2:

```
d = {u'{"options_selected":{"Ideas":"0"},"criterion_feedback":{},"overall_feedback":"Feedback_text_goes_here_1"}': [u'']}
d1 = {u'{"options_selected":{"Ideas":"2"},"criterion_feedback":{},"overall_feedback":"Feedback_text_goes_here_2"}': [u'']}

df = pd.DataFrame({'userid':[1,1],
                   'sub_id':[np.nan, 5],
                   'event':[d,d1]})

df['event'] = df['event'].astype(str).apply(yaml.load).apply(lambda x : yaml.load(list(x.keys())[0]))

print (type(df.event.iloc[0]))
<class 'dict'>

print (df.event.apply(pd.Series)['overall_feedback'])
0    Feedback_text_goes_here_1
1    Feedback_text_goes_here_2
Name: overall_feedback, dtype: object
```

Comment: thanks, could you please explain what is `combine_first`?

Comment: It replace NaN, similar as fillna.

Comment: What is `print (type(df.loc[0, 'event']))` ?

Comment: I see, I appreciate it! what if the `event` value was something like this: `{post:{'score':25, 'sub_id':5}}`

Comment: Sir, I am receiving `IndexError: list index out of range` error using the `fillna` option. I think `sub_id` is filtered by NA values therefore its length is  less than `event` column.

Comment: Regarding your previous question, it is `<type 'str'>`. I will use `str.split` to extract the info. But, I am receiving the `IndexError: list index out of range` error.

Comment: Dataframe is created from json?

Comment: No, it is a dataset from google bigquery. Thanks for the help. I will try your solutions!

Comment: Ok, I add solutions for converting strings to dict.

Comment: Yes, `print (type(df.loc[0, 'event']))` is `list` or `str` ?

Comment: both of these `print (type(pr_0_missing.loc[0, 'event'])), (type(pr_0_missing.loc[0, 'POST']))` return  `<type 'dict'>`. For some reason, it cannot parse `{u'{"options_selected":{"Ideas":"0"},"criterion_feedback":{},"overall_feedback":"Feedback_text_goes_here_1"}': [u'']}`

Comment: Hmmm, it seems it is dict in outer, but inner is string `'{"options_selected":{"Ideas":"0"},"criterion_feedback":{}‌​,"overall_feedback":‌​"Feedback_text_goes_‌​here_1"}'`. Do you try `df['event'] = df['event'].apply(ast.literal_eval)` or `df['event'] = df['event'].apply(yaml.load)`? Or maybe need `df['event'] = df['event'].astype(str)` first.

Comment: Yes! What is this going to help `df['event'] = df['event'].astype(str)` ?

Comment: It was only idea, give me a sec, I try test it.

Comment: I get it, but not easy, because need extract key from dict and parse again. Cech edited answer.

Comment: ;) No problem, nice day!